# Rails 4 - How do I create an object from multiple models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4, messaging

this is my 1st question so please feel free to ask if something is not clear and I will reply right away:

I'm working on a Rails 4 project -   I want to be able to send a custom message from one user to another.

I have 3 models that should apply to this question:  User, Track (meta info about a music track), TrackMessage.

the model TrackMessage has 4 fields:  id,  track_id, sender_id, recipient_id  .

I want to be able to use the track_id and sender_id to create a single object that contains the track object the track_id refers to, and the user object the sender_id refers to.

Ideally, in show.html.erb I'd like to be able to call:

```
<% @myMessages.each do | m | %>

     <p> <%= m.track.url %> </p>
     <p> <%= m.track.name %> </p>
     <p> <%= m.user.username %> </p>
     <p> <%= m.track.url %> </p>

<% end %>
```

in the User controller I have:

```
def show

   # fetch all of the messages that were sent to the current user
   @trackMessages = TrackMessage.where(:recipient_id => current_user.id)

   @myMessages = [ ]

   *stuck on what happens next:

end
```

I would absolutely love the community's help on this. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: What is your problem? Do you wanna to ask how to defined the TrackMessage model and how to create TrackMessage record with a track and user instance?

Comment: Hey nickcen - thank you for your response. You got it, and Baloo helped me solve it. Take care!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set it up like this.

In your controller

```
def show
  @track_messages = TrackMessage.includes(:track, :sender).where(:recipient_id => current_user.id)
end
```

TrackMessage model

```
Class TrackMessage
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :track
  delegate :name, to: :track, prefix: true
  delegate :url, to: :track, prefix: true
  delegate :username, to: :sender, prefix: true
end
```

Then in your view you should be able to do

```
<% @track_messages.each do | m | %>    
  <p> <%= m.track_url %> </p>
  <p> <%= m.track_name %> </p>
  <p> <%= m.sender_username %> </p>    
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the incredibly fast response - I'm going to try it out when I get home today and let you know!! Again - thanks so much.

Comment: This worked like a charm! I was wondering if I could contract an hour of your time to understand how this works exactly. I'm new to stackoverflow and don't know what the rules are exactly, but you really helped me out and I'd love to understand more about the syntax and principles. Get in touch at musicstartups@gmail.com